# Will the same value trigger the event in LiveDate?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

The Code A and Image A is from the artical [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150).

The author told me *"Trigger the event by setting a new Event as a new value"*, I think it should be *"Trigger the event by setting a new Event as any value"*, right?

For example,

Step 1: The user clicks the button in  master Activity with the code  `userClicksOnButton("StartDetails")` , the Details Activity will start.

Step 2: The user presses back, coming back to the master activity

Step 3:  The user clicks the button in  master Activity with the code  `userClicksOnButton("StartDetails")` again, the Details Activity will start again.

Is it right?

**Code A**

```
class ListViewModel : ViewModel {
    private val _navigateToDetails = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()

    val navigateToDetails : LiveData<Event<String>>
        get() = _navigateToDetails


    fun userClicksOnButton(itemId: String) {
        _navigateToDetails.value = Event(itemId)  // Trigger the event by setting a new Event as a new value
    }
}

open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}

myViewModel.navigateToDetails.observe(this, Observer {
    it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { // Only proceed if the event has never been handled
        startActivity(DetailsActivity...)
    }
})
```

Image A
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having two different constraints on the data.

The `LiveData` emits every update to active observers, but the event itself is stateful. Thus a **new** event is required as a new `LiveData` value. The `itemId` could be any value, but the comment doesn't refer to it.

> Trigger the event by setting a new Event as [a new] value

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that "Trigger the event by setting a new Event as any value" is correct?

Comment: I think _a new value_ is better than _any value_, because it refers to the `value` property of `LiveData`. Maybe `the new value` might be even better to reduce the confusion. With your interpretation _with any value_ might be better than _as any value_, but I really don't think the comment intents to make a statement about the value provided as `itemId`.